# Magento 2 - Get stacktrace

Tags: magento2, debugging

I try to figure out the exact stack trace after I click on a link for example the link which prints the order PDF in the customer area.

I tried it by adding the following code after `$response = $application->launch();`:

```
// vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php

    ...
    $response = $application->launch();

    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/zend_debug.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    
    // Stacktrace:
    
        $debugBackTrace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS);
        foreach ($debugBackTrace as $item) {
            $logger->info(@$item['class'] . @$item['type'] . @$item['function']);
        } 
    ...
```

But it just logs "**Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run**".

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$debugBackTrace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS);
foreach ($debugBackTrace as $item) {
    $logger->info($item['class'] . $item['type'] . $item['function']);
}
```

Comment: I tried it. There is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native Magento backtrace function from the \Magento\Framework\Debug class and call it whenever you need:

```
\Magento\Framework\Debug::backtrace(false, true, false);
```

The Result, you will get the debug-backtrace as :
[image]

Comment: Does not work. It just returns "true" and even if I place an "exit" just after it, it does not print anything.